# How much should I worry about battery fires?

Tags: batteries, safety, storage

I have a Li-Ion battery (built into a small spot welder device)
with 5Ah capacity (and 650A short-term current drive) that I will
probably not use for the next 3 months.  It's now charged to
about 50% capacity and I would rather not discharge it more since
battery lifetime is supposedly best when stored at 50%.

So, my only real worry now is that it might have some defect, short
itself, and light on fire in the next 3 months.  Is that paranoia?
If not, how should I store it for these 3 months?

It seems that I could buy an airtight fireproof bag for $10, but I
doubt everyone else with similar batteries is doing this.  How does
the risk of this battery causing a fire compare to my other household
electric fire risks (for example, I am now starting to worry about
my old 1970s 120V AC circuit breaker box)?

Comment: Have you dusted the breaker box? If dust catches it spreads quickly...

Comment: A bag sold for $10  is probably not both airtight as well as fireproof. If the seal is airtight at room temperature it will fail at the temperature of a fire. If it is airtight at the temperature of a fire, it will fail at room temperature. The sealing material will not have the necessary flexibility over such a wide temperature range. Many popular materials for seals used below some 100 °C will be destroyed by a fire. Thermal expansion of many materials will exceed the tolerances of the seal gap.

Comment: Where do you store your cell phone and your laptop computer????    Basically, don't store that device in your sock drawer or anywhere else it's surrounded by easily combustible materials, it really shouldn't be a problem.   You can YouTube lots of examples of people intentionally poking holes in those same size batteries.  It's spectacular, but short lived.

Comment: I fly battery powered planes, with 5 cell 3000mAh LiPo batteries.  I keep my batteries in steel ammo boxes, on a concrete floor, about a foot from a sheetrock wall and away from other flammable stuff.  If they go off I expect my shop will be filled with really nasty smelling smoke and I may need to buy a new charger (it lives next to the batteries), but I don't expect I'll be buying a new shop building.

Comment: Oh -- _in a different room than my paint storage cabinet_.  In case you're wondering.

Comment: @KyleB Well, at least my cell phone and laptop are close by, so I can extinguish any fire more quickly.  They also don't have 650A capability.  Anyway, I would be tempted to store them specially too if it were for 3 months, but see your point that this is paranoia.

Comment: @TimWescott You've convinced me to move my battery from a wooden table to the top shelf of a steel welding cart.  From an energy standpoint, it seems I can just consider my battery to be like 0.5g of gasoline, and store it such that, even if it lights on fire, the fire could not spread.  You could make this into an official answer,

Comment: @bobuhito Don't be misled by that "650A" rating.   I have one of those same machines.  It can put out massive current for milliseconds.   A small pulse, just long enough to make the spot weld.  It definitely can not do that for any period of time longer than a spark.   Note it uses the exact same kind of batteries that your laptop, any USB powerbank, any powertool "battery" pack, etc, will use.  THat's why all these devices are about the same physical size.   "18650" is most common size probably.

Answer (score 1):

(Compiled from comments by me and the OP)

I fly battery powered planes, with 5 cell 3000mAh LiPo batteries.  Per model aviation practice, I keep my in containers, and the containers away from flammable materials.  Note that this is a slight excess of caution for most consumer packs, which are managed -- model aviation packs are "naked", with no protective circuitry.

I keep my batteries in steel ammo boxes, on a concrete floor, about a foot from a sheetrock wall and away from other flammable stuff.  My solvent-based paints are *well* away. If they go off I expect my shop will be filled with really nasty smelling smoke and I may need to buy a new charger (it lives next to the batteries), but I don't expect I'll be buying a new shop building.

> You've convinced me to move my battery from a wooden table to the top shelf of a steel welding cart. From an energy standpoint, it seems I can just consider my battery to be like 0.5g of gasoline, and store it such that, even if it lights on fire, the fire could not spread.

There's some similarities and differences, but they probably add up to roughly similar levels of risk.  Batteries carry their own "fuel" and "oxidizer".  Gasoline is highly flammable and liquid, but needs air to burn.

So under the right circumstances you could conceivably put out a gasoline fire -- with batteries you have to wait it out, possibly after dumping a bunch of sand or dirt on them to contain the flames.